# How to change the themes of a specific range in an Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I know how to change the themes of the entire worksheet in an Excel file: **Page Layout > Themes > Themes**. But how to change the theme of a specific range (not all the worksheets/workbook) in a worksheet in Excel 2010 please?

Comment: conditionnal formating is not enough in your case ?

Comment: I just thought about using themes.

Comment: I don't think you can. The themes affect the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the range to a table.  Select any cell in the range, then from the Insert ribbon choose Table.

A default style will be applied.  From the Table Tools / Design ribbon you can choose from a range of Table Styles.

Comment: Dear Mike, I talked about themes not styles. Anyway, thanks.